# Cassandra nodes appearing in different datacenters

Tags: cassandra, yaml, nosql

I am having trouble with three nodes in Cassandra, each of them in an individual computer, as I am trying to set up my first Cassandra structure. I have set up everything as in the Datastax documentation, and I have the same configuration in the different cassandra.yaml of each machine (changing the relative ips). The thing is that after configuring everything, each computer sees each other as DN, and each machine (localhost) appears as UN, with the difference that in the .101 computer I can see two different datacenters, while in the other computers only one datacenter appears.

So in my 192.168.1.101 machine when I type

```
sudo nodetool status
```

I get this output:

```
Datacenter: DC1
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address        Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
DN  192.168.1.200  ?          256          ?       968d5d1e-a113-40ce-9521-e392a927ea5e  r1
DN  192.168.1.102  ?          256          ?       fc5c2dbe-8834-4040-9e77-c3d8199b6767  r1
Datacenter: dc1
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address        Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  127.0.0.1      446.13 KB  256          ?       6d28d540-2b44-4522-8612-b5f70a3d7d52  rack1
```

While when I type "nodetool status" in one of the other two machines, I get this output:

```
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address        Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
DN  192.168.1.200  ?          256          ?       968d5d1e-a113-40ce-9521-e392a927ea5e  rack1
UN  127.0.0.1      506,04 KB  256          ?       fc5c2dbe-8834-4040-9e77-c3d8199b6767  rack1
DN  192.168.1.101  ?          256          ?       6d28d540-2b44-4522-8612-b5f70a3d7d52  rack1
```

In OpsCenter I can only see my 192.168.1.101 machine:

[image: OpsCenter displaying only one node]

... Which makes me think that something's odd in the yaml file of this machine and the others, but I have checked several times and it seems that the configuration is the same in the other computers. Enpoint_snitch is set to "GossipingPropertyFileSnitch".

Any tips on how to solve the reason why all the other nodes appear as Down Normal and why I am getting two datacenters would be highly appreaciated. It's driving me crazy!

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like some of the installed nodes were dead, so I deleted the nodes that were not the local machine in each of the nodes, ie:

```
nodetool removenode 968d5d1e-a113-40ce-9521-e392a927ea5e
nodetool removenode fc5c2dbe-8834-4040-9e77-c3d8199b6767
```

and after that I got the right output when I executed nodetools status

```
[machine1]~$ sudo nodetool status
Datacenter: dc1
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address    Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  127.0.0.1  286.93 KB  256          ?       6d28d540-2b44-4522-8612-b5f70a3d7d52  rack1


[machine2]~$ sudo nodetool status
Datacenter: dc1
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address    Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  127.0.0.1  268.45 KB  256          ?       fc5c2dbe-8834-4040-9e77-c3d8199b6767  rack1
```

And made sure that the parameters cluster_name, seeds, listen_address and rpc_address were right.

```
cluster_name: 'Test Cluster'
seeds: "192.168.1.101, 192.168.1.102"
listen_address: 192.168.1.101
rpc_address: 192.168.1.101
```

Changing listen_address and rpc_address to the corresponding ip of each machine in their corresponding cassandra.yaml file.

After that I got the right output (I am using only 2 machines for the nodes now):

```
Datacenter: dc1
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address        Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  192.168.1.101  309.13 KB  256          51.6%             6d28d540-2b44-4522-8612-b5f70a3d7d52  rack1
UN  192.168.1.102  257.15 KB  256          48.4%             fc5c2dbe-8834-4040-9e77-c3d8199b6767  rack1
```

Answer (score 0):

> Any tips on how to solve the reason why all the other nodes appear as Down Normal and why I am getting two datacenters would be highly appreaciated. It's driving me crazy!

On each machine, edit the **$CASSANDRA_HOME/conf/cassandra-rackdc.properties** file to set:

```
dc=dc1
rack=rack1
```

*nodetool status* shows that you set the wrong DC name for 2 nodes (DC1 instead of dc1). It's **case sensitive**

Comment: I didn't touch that file at all, and editing them I can see that they're just as you stated, so there must be another reason of the wrong behaviour of my implementation. I'm attaching a screenshot of the opened files through 3 secure shells: 

http://i.imgur.com/TN26obb.png